# Scalable, global variable assignment @mixin for Sass

Tags: css, sass, namespaces

I thought that I had already solved this, but the code is not compiling in the way that I intend.

Here is my current code:

```
$prefix: 'foo';

@mixin var-assign($var, $val) {
  $var: $val !global;
};

// will output .foo-selector
.#{$prefix}-selector {
  /* ... */
}

@include var-assign($prefix, 'bar');

// should output .bar-selector
.#{$prefix}-selector {
  /* ... */
}
```

The code above prints `.foo-selector` twice. Where am I going wrong that I am not printing one instance of `.foo-selector` ad one instance of `.bar-selector`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to changes in your mixin variable, Try using

```
@mixin var-assign($prefix, $val) {
  $prefix: $val !global;
};
```

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LByOrr):

Comment: This seems to work only when the @mixin argument shares that same name as the initial global variable. Change `$prefix` in the global scope or in the @mixin so that original declaration name doesn't reflect the argument's name and it breaks. I need a scalable solution for altering variable values.